# How to scale ticks on an axis in proportion

Tags: python, matplotlib

The numbers I have on y-axis might be distributed in a broad range. What I want is simply having the axis with these ticks [5,10,15,20,50,100,500,1000,1500,2000,2500], but proportionally distributed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
x_axis = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y").date() for date in ['06/03/23', '13/03/23']]
y1 = [2400, 1900]
y2 = [1800, 1800]
y3 = [4, 3]
plt.plot(x_axis, y1, label="1")
plt.plot(x_axis, y2, label="2")
plt.plot(x_axis, y3, label="3")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xticks(x_axis)
plt.yticks([5,10,15,20,50,100,500,1000,1500,2000,2500])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in solution for this, but you can define your own scale as a succession of linear scales with [FuncScale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale) (I changed your ticks a bit to make for easier calculation but I hope you get the idea):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.scale import FuncScale
from datetime import datetime

def scale_func(x):
    y = x.copy()
    for i, e in enumerate(x):
        if e > 500:
            y[i] = 55 + 0.01*e
        elif e > 100:
            y[i] = 35 + 0.05*e
        elif e > 20:
            y[i] = 15 + 0.25*e
    return y

def scale_func_inverse(x):
    y = x.copy()
    for i, e in enumerate(x):
        if e > 60:
            y[i] = 100*(e-55)
        elif e > 40:
            y[i] = 20*(e-35)
        elif e > 20:
            y[i] = 4*(e-15)
    return y


x_axis = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y").date() for date in ['06/03/23', '13/03/23']]
y1 = [2400, 1900]
y2 = [1800, 1800]
y3 = [4, 3]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x_axis, y1, label="1")
plt.plot(x_axis, y2, label="2")
plt.plot(x_axis, y3, label="3")

scale = FuncScale(ax, functions=(scale_func, scale_func_inverse))
ax.set_yscale(scale)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xticks(x_axis)
yticks = [5,10,15,20,40,60,80,100,200,300,400,500,1000,1500,2000,2500]
plt.yticks(yticks, yticks)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is a very good answer! Thank you a lot, I could easily implement it into my work. Learned something new today!